# Amazon S3 filenames with Unicode Latin-1 supplement 0080 - 00FF characters

Tags: java, amazon-s3, unicode, utf-8, iso-8859-1

I have a requirement to upload and download files in a S3 bucket where the filenames can contain Unicode characters from the range 0020 to 00FF. I am able to upload and download the files with this Unicode range from AWS command line.

However when using Java sdk for S3, the special characters in Unicode range 0080 - 00FF are being interpreted with Â.

For example:

file in S3 bucket is file-1£.xml

The files is read as file-1Â£.xml

I noticed same issue with ftp and I was able to set ftpClient.controlEncoding=UTF-8, which fixed the issue and ftp was able to read the filename properly. Is there something similar for s3 client?